# How to move image up and overflow one part of image and other not

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am making a site in CSS and have trouble the entire day making one part of the image hidden when it overflows and another not and also moving image up and down.
Here is the HTML code:

```
    <section class="next-gen">
    <div class="text-content">
        <h1>Next generation <br>
            digital banking</h1>
        <p>Take your financial life online. Your Easybank account <br> will be a one-stop-shop for spending,
            saving,<br>
            budgeting, investing, and much more.</p>
        <button class="request-button">Request Invite</button>
    </div>
    <div class="image-content">
        <img src="images/bg-intro-desktop.svg" alt="" class="image-1">
        <img src="images/image-mockups.png" alt="" class="image-2">

    </div>
</section>[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

This is the CSS for this div:

```
 .next-gen{
    
    padding-left: 10%;
    background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 98%);
    font-family: "Public Sans", sans-serif;
    display: flex;
    height: 450px;
}
.text-content p{
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    color: hsl(233, 8%, 62%);
}
.image-content {
    position: absolute;   
    left: 1000px;
    overflow: hidden;
   
}

.image-2 {
  position: absolute;
  right: 250px;
  bottom: 210px;
  z-index: 5;
 }
```

I didn't find a similar question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if I am thinking right you have two images **Image-1** for the background and **Image-2** which is the image of the phones.

```
.image-content {
    position: absolute;   
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url("images/bg-intro-desktop.svg");
}

.image-2 {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: /*align it so that it comes in the center of the main div*/
  z-index: 5; /*Less Than your z-index of nav if have if not add a higher z-index than this to your nav*/
 }
```

Now the div where you have the text and the button gives it a

> position: relative;

and a use min-width instead of width **IF HAVE**

and most probably it will solve your problem if not please provide some more information including the div in which you have the text and the button.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It almost solved my problem it placed it correctly and only one part of the image is hidden but now there is another problem background image is not hidden in the below part and also bg image should be more up I will provide more info.

Comment: can you give the CSS code of **next-gen** section

Comment: Yes, I updated it

Comment: Remove this **height: 450px;** and use **min-height: 450px;** and that should work.

Comment: It didn't change, still same.

Comment: I just need to cut background image from bottom and top

Comment: [I hope this will help you](https://codepen.io/devrud2022/pen/BaPNpKy)

Comment: Thank you for help will approve your answer.